# Android: what is the minSdk value that I should set for my app?

Tags: android, gradle

I have recently received a warning from Google in the developer console stating that my app must target Android 13 (API level 33).
I am a bit confused about what I'm supposed to set in the `build.gradle` file.

This is currently what I have:

```
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        // ...
    }
}
```

Do I need to change something here? I'm confused by this warning.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need to change anything now in your gradle as you've already set it to API level 33.

For more, you can check Google Play's target API level requirement documentation
https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk

And as you set minSdk to 21 in your Android app's build configuration, it means that your app requires a minimum of Android 5.0 Lollipop (API level 21) in order to run. This implies that your app won't be installable or functional on devices running Android versions earlier than 5.0 Lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to affected bundles, maybe it is testing bundles that you forgot to update.
[image]